# Copy entire rows based on multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My first sheet is the template were all the values will be put in by the user.
The second sheet is where I want the information copied to.

I created a CommandButton that copies over the first lot of information (that is the Company logo, Company info and Client inf).

My second CommandButton is where my problem starts.
I have entire rows to copy based on the value in column "O".
If Column "O" is >= 1 OR if Column "O" has an "x" then that row should be copied. So far it copies the "x" over without a specific line of code stating that.

-When I run the code it starts copying to row 1. I need it to start copying to row 34
-If the value in column "O" is "x" then it copies that row but then it copies the next row over that previous one, it does not move to the next row. However when it copies over rows with values >1 then it moves to the next row and copies that.

```vb
'Sheet1 is named Template1
'Sheet2 is named Copy data
 
a = Worksheets("Template1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
For i = 34 To a
    If Worksheets("Template1").Cells(i, 15) >= 1 Then
        Worksheets("Template1").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Copy data").Activate
        
        B = Worksheets("Copy data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         
        Worksheets("Copy data").Cells(B + 1, 1).Select
        
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Template1").Activate
        
    End If
Next
 
Apllication.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template1").Cells(1, 1).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it benefits your business

```
Dim lr As Integer, alan As Range
Dim sa1 As Worksheet, sa2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set sa1 = Worksheets("Template1")
Set sa2 = Worksheets("Copy data")
lr = sa1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set alan = sa1.Range("A34", "O" & lr)

For i = 34 To alan.Rows.Count + 34
        If sa1.Cells(i, 15) >= 1 Or sa1.Cells(i, 15) = "x" Then
                sa1.Range("a" & i).Resize(, alan.Columns.Count).Copy _
                sa2.Range("A" & sa2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)
        End If
Next i
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).